# Android - Firebase replaces data

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing an android application where older kids can pick up younger kids and walk to school. With the application, the authenticated (email and password) younger kid can choose between three addresses to get picked up. I have a user node and an address node.

The problem is that every time a user picks an address, the username child is overridden. Therefore there will only be one username per address.
**My database structure looks like this:**

[image: a]

```
database.child("Addresses").child(m1.getStreet()).child("username").setValue(name);
database.child("Addresses").child(m2.getStreet()).child("time").setValue(time);
database.child("Addresses").child(m3.getStreet()).child("address").setValue(address);
```

I thought about using the push function, but I don't think it can be used in this context. Any ideas?

Comment: when a user picks and address where are you saving it

Comment: In the address node

Answer (score 1):

`setValue()` will override everything in the existing map. Use [`updateChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren) if you want to add/update values and keep the old data.

Comment: There no methods called updateValues() – JDoe 22 mins ago

Comment: @JDoe I am sorry I thought Swift and Android had the same method names. See the edit Frank has done, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique usernames or if you can get the keys in User, you can directly use that as a key:

```
database.child("Addresses").child(m1.getStreet()).child("users").child(name).child("username").setValue(name);
database.child("Addresses").child(m2.getStreet()).child("users").child(name).child("time").setValue(time);
database.child("Addresses").child(m3.getStreet()).child("users").child(name).child("address").setValue(address);
```